# Spark Scala - Aggregation and Pivoting Based on Time Period

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, pivot-table, aggregate

I was trying to implement pivoting similar to sql server in spark

As of now, I'm using sqlContext and applying all the transformation within the sql.
I would like to know if I can do a direct pull from sql server and implement the pivot funtion using spark.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve-
SQL Server queries below-

`create table #temp(ID Int, MonthPrior int, Amount float);`

`insert into #temp 
values (100,1,10),(100,2,20),(100,3,30),(100,4,10),(100,5,20),(100,6,60),(200,1,10),(200,2,20),(200,3,30),(300,4,10),(300,5,20),(300,6,60);`

`select * from #temp;`

|**ID** |**MonthPrior**|**Amount**|
|-------|----------|------|
|100    |1  |10|
|100    |2  |20|
|100    |3  |30|
|100    |4  |10|
|100    |5  |20|
|100    |6  |60|
|200    |1  |10|
|200    |2  |20|
|200    |3  |30|
|300    |4  |10|
|300    |5  |20|
|300    |6  |60|

`Select ID,coalesce([1],0) as Amount1Mth, coalesce([1],0)+coalesce([2],0)+coalesce([3],0) as Amount1to3Mth, coalesce([1],0)+coalesce([2],0)+coalesce([3],0)+coalesce([4],0)+coalesce([5],0)+coalesce([6],0) as Amount_AllMonths from (select  * from #temp) A
pivot
( sum(Amount) for MonthPrior in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]) ) as Pvt`

|**ID** |**Amount1Mth** |**Amount1to3Mth**  |**Amount_AllMonths**|
|-------|-------|-------|---|
|100    |10 |60 |150|
|200    |10 |60 |60|
|300    |0  |0  |90|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Amount` column is of `Decimal` type, it would be best to use `java.math.BigDecimal` as the corresponding argument type.  Note that methods `+` and `sum` are no longer applicable hence are replaced with `add` and `reduce` respectively.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.math.BigDecimal

val df = Seq(
  (100, 1, new BigDecimal(10)),
  (100, 2, new BigDecimal(20)),
  (100, 3, new BigDecimal(30)),
  (100, 4, new BigDecimal(10)),
  (100, 5, new BigDecimal(20)),
  (100, 6, new BigDecimal(60)),
  (200, 1, new BigDecimal(10)),
  (200, 2, new BigDecimal(20)),
  (200, 3, new BigDecimal(30)),
  (300, 4, new BigDecimal(10)),
  (300, 5, new BigDecimal(20)),
  (300, 6, new BigDecimal(60))
).toDF("ID", "MonthPrior", "Amount")

// UDF to combine 2 array-type columns to map
def arrayToMap = udf(
  (a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[BigDecimal]) => (a zip b).toMap
)

// Create array columns which get zipped into a map
val df2 = df.groupBy("ID").agg(
  collect_list(col("MonthPrior")).as("MonthList"),
  collect_list(col("Amount")).as("AmountList")
).select(
  col("ID"), arrayToMap(col("MonthList"), col("AmountList")).as("MthAmtMap")
)

// UDF to sum map values for keys from 1 thru n (0 for all)
def sumMapValues = udf(
  (m: Map[Int, BigDecimal], n: Int) =>
    if (n > 0)
      m.collect{ case (k, v) => if (k <= n) v else new BigDecimal(0) }.reduce(_ add _)
    else
      m.collect{ case (k, v) => v }.reduce(_ add _)
)

val df3 = df2.withColumn( "Amount1Mth", sumMapValues(col("MthAmtMap"), lit(1)) ).
  withColumn( "Amount1to3Mth", sumMapValues(col("MthAmtMap"), lit(3)) ).
  withColumn( "Amount_AllMonths", sumMapValues(col("MthAmtMap"), lit(0)) ).
  select( col("ID"), col("Amount1Mth"), col("Amount1to3Mth"), col("Amount_AllMonths") )

df3.show(truncate=false)
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| ID|          Amount1Mth|       Amount1to3Mth|    Amount_AllMonths|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|300|               0E-18|               0E-18|90.00000000000000...|
|100|10.00000000000000...|60.00000000000000...|150.0000000000000...|
|200|10.00000000000000...|60.00000000000000...|60.00000000000000...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a map-type column from arrays of `MonthPrior` and `Amount`, and apply a `UDF` that sum the map values based on an integer parameter:

```
val df = Seq(
  (100, 1, 10),
  (100, 2, 20),
  (100, 3, 30),
  (100, 4, 10),
  (100, 5, 20),
  (100, 6, 60),
  (200, 1, 10),
  (200, 2, 20),
  (200, 3, 30),
  (300, 4, 10),
  (300, 5, 20),
  (300, 6, 60)
).toDF("ID", "MonthPrior", "Amount")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// UDF to combine 2 array-type columns to map
def arrayToMap = udf(
  (a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) => (a zip b).toMap
)

// Aggregate columns into arrays and apply arrayToMap UDF to create map column
val df2 = df.groupBy("ID").agg(
  collect_list(col("MonthPrior")).as("MonthList"),
  collect_list(col("Amount")).as("AmountList")
).select(
  col("ID"), arrayToMap(col("MonthList"), col("AmountList")).as("MthAmtMap")
)

// UDF to sum map values for keys from 1 thru n (0 for all)
def sumMapValues = udf(
  (m: Map[Int, Int], n: Int) =>
    if (n > 0) m.collect{ case (k, v) => if (k <= n) v else 0 }.sum else
      m.collect{ case (k, v) => v }.sum
)

// Apply sumMapValues UDF to the map column
val df3 = df2.withColumn( "Amount1Mth", sumMapValues(col("MthAmtMap"), lit(1)) ).
  withColumn( "Amount1to3Mth", sumMapValues(col("MthAmtMap"), lit(3)) ).
  withColumn( "Amount_AllMonths", sumMapValues(col("MthAmtMap"), lit(0)) ).
  select( col("ID"), col("Amount1Mth"), col("Amount1to3Mth"), col("Amount_AllMonths") )

df3.show
+---+----------+-------------+----------------+
| ID|Amount1Mth|Amount1to3Mth|Amount_AllMonths|
+---+----------+-------------+----------------+
|300|         0|            0|              90|
|100|        10|           60|             150|
|200|        10|           60|              60|
+---+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, @LeoC
I will analyze this approach. Seems to work

Comment: (a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) => (a zip b).toMap is giving issues. I'm working on this 

`cannot resolve 'UDF(col_1,col_2)' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires array<int> type, however, 'col_2' is of array<decimal(38,18)> type.`

Tried using number/decimal in udf. Still didn't work

Comment: Sounds like your `Amount` column is of type `Decimal`.  It should be trivial to modify the argument type of the existing `UDF`s to adapt to the said type.  Certain arithmetic methods might have to be adjusted though.

Comment: @ashok viswanathan, to avoid a lengthy update I've posted a solution for the `Decimal` type as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LeoC. above solution worked. I also tried the following-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column


lazy val months = (((df select ($"MonthPrior") distinct) sort 
($"MonthPrior".asc)).rdd map (_.getAs[Int](0)) collect).toList

lazy val sliceSpec = List((0, 2, "1-2"), (0, 3, "1-3"), (0, 4, "1-4"), (0, 5, "1-5"), (0, 6, "1-6"))

lazy val createGroup: List[Any] => ((Int, Int, String) => Column) = sliceMe => (start, finish, aliasName) =>
  sliceMe slice (start, finish) map (value => col(value.toString)) reduce (_ + _) as aliasName

lazy val grouper = createGroup(months).tupled

lazy val groupedCols = sliceSpec map (group => grouper(group))

val pivoted = df groupBy ($"ID") pivot ("MonthPrior") agg (sum($"Amount"))

val writeMe = pivoted select ((pivoted.columns map col) ++ (groupedCols): _*)

z.show(writeMe sort ($"ID".asc))
```